# Margins between columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, twitter-bootstrap-3

So the new Bootstrap v3 code looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 bg-red">
       <h2>Heading</h2>
       <p>My text here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 bg-green">
       <h2>Heading</h2>
       <p>My text here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 bg-blue">
       <h2>Heading</h2>
       <p>My text here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Because Bootstrap 3 has removed column margins (now has padding left and right). How can I put a background color on the `class="col-lg-4"` div and have the page background gap between each div?

Note: it must be a background color on the `class="col-lg-4"` div.

Comment: For this particular example somehow it should be possible.. but for the whole Bootstrap with these requirements that you are asking.. not worth it.. use BS2 or put the contents in a wrapper..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the [`background-clip`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-clip) property with the `content-box` value so that the painting area is clipped to the content box of `.col-lg-4` instead of the border box like it is by default.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.col-*-3` and add margin to it. You have 4 columns but the 4th is unused and then you have room for the margins. Here's an example:

http://www.bootply.com/R9iSDcNuzY

`HTML`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 bg-danger col-margin">
       <h2>Heading</h2>
       <p>My text here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 bg-success col-margin">
       <h2>Heading</h2>
       <p>My text here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 bg-primary col-margin">
       <h2>Heading</h2>
       <p>My text here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

`CSS`

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.col-margin{
    margin: 10px;
}
```